# Creating a symbolic link from name.md to README.md

Tags: github, markdown, symlink, readme

I've tried using

`ln -s ./name.md .github/README.md`

Nothing happens and I cannot commit a change that would allow me to have the file "name.md" displayed as "README.md" this is some sort of link together.

Does anyone know of a solution to link my "name.md" file to the "README.md" file?

I just want to continue writing with the document named "name.md" instead of having to commit to a "README.md" file every time. I would rather it just have a symbolic link that supplies content from "name.md?" to "README.md"

These are in one repo.

Linguistics Repo :

```
LingRepo -

./.github/
../README.md
./named-notes.md
```

https://github.com/popados/LING_Research